# Promesa dentro de una promesa query

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, promesas

Hola amigos quiero hacer un query, pero quiero hacer otros query dependiendo de la respuesta de el primero. Algo así

```js
const queryalumn = pool.query('INSERT INTO alumnos_ set  ?', [alumno]);
queryalumn.then((err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  if (res.length > 0) {
    const alumn = res[0];
    // console.log(alumn);

    const id = alumn.insertId;
    const cartera = {
      id_alumno: id
    }
    //return id;

    const querycart = pool.query('INSERT INTO cartera_ set  ?', [cartera]);
    querycart.then((err, res) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const cart = res[0];
      console.log(cart);
      const idcart = res.insertId;
      console.log(idcart);


    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });

  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

el problema es que me undefined en el segundo query, eventualmente voy a querer hacer otro query con la respuesta de **cartera** , alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola, sé que esta pregunta ya tiene su tiempo. Pero revisando bien tu sentencia SQL, veo que tienes un error de falta de asignación. Pones: `'INSERT INTO alumnos_ set  ?', [alumno]`, a mi parecer te falta la asignación, es decir: `'INSERT INTO alumnos_ set alumno = ?', [alumno]`. Lo mismo para la tabla `cartera_`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rawrdríguez.Ophanim,

Yo para este caso utilizaria 'async/await'.

Te adjunto el codigo que debería de funcionarte añadiendo la correccion de nuestro amigo @Mauricio Contreras:

```
const example = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await pool.query('INSERT INTO alumnos_ set  alumno = ?', [alumno]);

        if (res.length > 0) {
            const alumn = res[0];

            const cartera = {id_alumno: alumn.insertId}

            const resCart = await pool.query('INSERT INTO cartera_ set cartera = ?', [cartera]);

            const cart = res[0];
            const idcart = cart.insertId;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Espero que te haya ayudado a solucionar el problema, en tal caso comenta de nuevo e intentamos solucionarlo.

Un saludo